# Can I recover overwritten file from SublimeText?

Tags: sublimetext, recovery

I do simple web page, based on HTML and CSS in editor Sublime Text. I overwided my index.html with another by mistake (drag and drop at wrong file). I have no time to write whole content of the page again. Is there any possibility to "take a look" at history in Sublime Text? My OS is Windows 7. I didnt do any backup.

Comment: I think no.... see why ... here at sublime forum http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3403

Comment: Yeah, I thought about something like Eclipse has - local history . Time to change the editor and be more careful (and do backups!). Thanks.

Comment: Ya much better option....good luck.Welcome

Comment: Why would you change the editor when it was your mistake?

Comment: I mean to find an editor with are more resistance to silly mistakes than Sublime Text.

Comment: I found that Sublime Text has some settings for backup. Never too late for improving knowledge. Thanks

Comment: there are even plugin that save a local history of the file each time you save or exit it

Answer (score 1):

> In pure sublime I do not know of any possibility to recover
>   overwritten files.

But there are backup [extensions](https://packagecontrol.io/search/backup) that might save you from the same issue in the future:

- **AutoBackups** by Avtandil Kikabidze aka LONGMAN 22 k Installs:
  Sublime Text 2/3 Auto backups plugin
- **BuffersBackup** by lewisjosh  627 Installs:
  A Sublime Text 2 plugin for backing up all open files/buffers on an periodic basis.
- **Automatic Backups** by joelpt 10K Installs: 
  Automatic backups with historical navigation for Sublime Text.
- **Create Backup Copy** by glutanimate ST3 1K Installs: 
  Sublime Text plugin that creates time-stamped backup copies of files
- **Local History** by vishr 62K Installs: 
  A Sublime Text 2/3 plugin for maintaining local history of files. [backup | open | compare | incremental diff]
- **Veeam Logs Helper** by yandexx ST3 217 Installs: 
  Veeam Backup & Replication logs syntax highlighting for Sublime Text